# Eslint me notifica en rojo que dos reglas en el fichero .eslintrc.cjs requieren que la opción `strictNullChecks` este activada

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

No entiendo esa notificación porque mi fichero  tsconfig.json tiene la opción y esta en true ,las dos reglas que me señala son :
@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition,
@typescript-eslint/prefer-nullish-coalescing
agradecería una mano si alguien ha tenido algo parecido , saludos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Jose, bienvenido, vamos por partes, el código y mensajes de error como texto, la descripción del problema en español, si tu pregunta tiene algún error de formato, no la elimines, edítala, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Answer (score 0):

La solución al Error Arriba comentado , donde existía inconsistencia entre las reglas:

- @typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition,
- @typescript-eslint/prefer-nullish-coalescing,
  del fichero: .eslintrc.cjs.y que ambas reglas necesitaban de la opción strictNullChecks` que estuviera activada.

Nota: Esta opción siempre estuvo activada,pero no era reconocida.

fue instalar el plugin:  eslint-plugin-strict-null-checks
Aquí la referencia: https://github.com/JaroslawPokropinski/eslint-plugin-strict-null-checks ,
muchas gracias